# How to define subheaders in table?

Tags: tables

I have the following table:

```
\begin{table}[]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{SSSSSSSS}
    \toprule
    {Method} & {Number of windows} & {Size of windows} \\ \midrule
    {Window warping} & 45 & 2 seconds \\
    {Windowed magnitude warping} & 40 & 3 seconds \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Fixed hyperparameters}
    \label{tab:fixed_hyperparameters}
\end{table}
```

and this table is displayed:

[image]

I have now different routes for which I have to define values and want to achieve something like this (pseudo code):

```
\begin{table}[]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{SSSSSSSS}
    \toprule
    {Method} & {Number of windows} & {Size of windows} \\ \midrule
    {Route 1} \\ \midrule % should be aligned in the middle
    {Window warping} & 45 & 2 seconds \\
    {Windowed magnitude warping} & 40 & 3 seconds \\ \midrule

    {Route 2} \\ \midrule % should be aligned in the middle
    {Window warping} & 30 & 5 seconds \\
    {Windowed magnitude warping} & 25 & 2 seconds \\ \midrule

    {Route 3} \\ \midrule % should be aligned in the middle
    {Window warping} & 55 & 1 seconds \\
    {Windowed magnitude warping} & 40 & 5 seconds \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Fixed hyperparameters}
    \label{tab:fixed_hyperparameters}
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why `S` columns? And why do you define eight columns when you use just three? The first column should definitely be not `S`, because it contains text. I have also doubts about the third column: how can a size be measured in seconds? In any case, you should not repeat “seconds” each time.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp] % <--- NOT []
\centering

\begin{tabular}{
  @{}
  l
  S[table-format=2.0]
  S[table-format=1.0]
  @{}
}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{@{}c}{Method} & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{Windows} \\
\cmidrule{2-3}
& {Number} & {Size (seconds)} \\
\midrule

\multicolumn{1}{@{}c}{\itshape Route 1} \\
Window warping & 45 & 2 \\
Windowed magnitude warping & 40 & 3 \\
\midrule

\multicolumn{1}{@{}c}{\itshape Route 2} \\
Window warping & 30 & 5 \\
Windowed magnitude warping & 25 & 2 \\
\midrule

\multicolumn{1}{@{}c}{\itshape Route 3} \\ 
Window warping & 55 & 1 \\
Windowed magnitude warping & 40 & 5 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\caption{Fixed hyperparameters}
\label{tab:fixed_hyperparameters}

\end{table}

\begin{table}[htp] % <--- NOT []
\centering

\begin{tabular}{
  @{}
  l
  S[table-format=2.0]
  S[table-format=1.0]
  @{}
}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{@{}c}{Method} & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{Windows} \\
\cmidrule{2-3}
& {Number} & {Size (seconds)} \\
\midrule

\qquad\itshape Route 1 \\
Window warping & 45 & 2 \\
Windowed magnitude warping & 40 & 3 \\
\midrule

\qquad\itshape Route 2 \\
Window warping & 30 & 5 \\
Windowed magnitude warping & 25 & 2 \\
\midrule

\qquad\itshape Route 3 \\
Window warping & 55 & 1 \\
Windowed magnitude warping & 40 & 5 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\caption{Fixed hyperparameters}
\label{tab:fixed_hyperparameters-again}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I wouldn't move “Route n” in the middle of the table, but either centered in the first column or a bit on the right, in a different font shape.

[image]

Comment: You are right. There are some inconsistencies I have to fix. Thank you for your help!